# Handle actions from Push notification actions synchronously

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, push

I would like to treat `push notification` actions synchronously by using a `FIFO`. Inside:

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo   completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
```

I have many blocks and I would like that when I receive an action, I add it (with its blocks) in a `FIFO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSOperationQueue* queue = [[ NSOperationQueue alloc ] init];
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

NSOperation* someOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^(void) { NSLog(@"Done.");}];

if (queue.operations.count != 0)
    [someOperation addDependency: queue.operations.lastObject];
```

You can also simply add a category to your NSOperationQueue:

```
@interface NSOperationQueue (FIFOQueue)
  - (void)addOperationAfterLast:(NSOperation *)op;
@end

@implementation NSOperationQueue (FIFOQueue)
- (void)addOperationAfterLast:(NSOperation *)op
  {
    if (self.maxConcurrentOperationCount != 1)
        self.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
        NSOperation* lastOp = self.operations.lastObject;
    if (lastOp != nil)
        [op addDependency: lastOp];
        [self addOperation:op];
    }
@end
```

and use [queue addOperationAfterLast:myOperation].

Comment: Thanks fot the answer but I have to call completionHandler();. I don't you how to do this using your method

Answer (score 0):

Try using this approach

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.myqueue", 0);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
  printf("1");
});
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
  printf("2");
});
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
  printf("3");
});
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
  printf("4");
});
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
  printf("5");
});
// wait for queue to empty
dispatch_sync(myQueue, ^{
  printf("done");
});
```